Returning Null Generic Type
I have a class:
public interface IA
{
    TValue? GetValue<TValue>();
}

public class A : IA
{
   public TValue? GetValue<TValue>()
   {
      ...

      if (value is not null)        
          return (TValue)value;

      return default(TValue);
   }
}

This is alright, but when I try to implement the interface explicitly:
public interface IA
{
    TValue? GetValue<TValue>();
}

public class A : IA
{
   TValue? IA.GetValue<TValue>()
   {
      ...

      if (value is not null)        
          return (TValue)value;

      return default(TValue);
   }
}

The compiler throws an error:
Cannot implicitly convert type TValue to TValue?

Is there a difference when implementing an interface explicitly? This seems to only be the case when dealing with a nullable generic return type.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Please share a [mcve].

You need to use default constraint:
TValue? IA.GetValue<TValue>() where TValue : default


To allow annotations for type parameters that are not constrained to reference types or value types


If you use your tooling to ask it to generate an explicit interface implementation you should find it applies where TValue : default to the implementation.
This is only required for the explicit interface implementation. See where clause

The addition of nullable reference types introduces a potential ambiguity in the meaning of T? in generic methods [...] The new default constraint resolves this ambiguity.

